# El significado de "cuenta" en "más de la cuenta"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Alguien sabe el significado de "cuenta" en "más de la cuenta"? Mi suposición es que tiene algo que ver con "número, porción, cantidad" ([RAE](https://dle.rae.es/cuenta)), pero no estoy seguro. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: En “más de la cuenta” “cuenta” es el “límite” o la “cantidad convenida” y el hablante transgredió ese límite, es decir, fue desproporcionado en relación a lo que se estila, espera, supone, necesita, imagina o de lo que se considera razonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Alguien sabe el significado de "cuenta" en "**más de la cuenta**"?

---

El significado de "**cuenta**", "en más de la cuenta" en este caso se refiere a más de lo normal, a demasiado, al exceso de algo.

Ejemplos

- No bebas más de la cuenta. (No bebas en exceso).
- No abuses más de la cuenta. (No abuses o te pases más de lo normal).
- El habla más de la cuenta. (El habla demasiado).

Provendría de la antigua costumbre de hacer la cuenta de lo que se llevaba consumido en las barras de las antiguas tabernas, muchas en ocasiones el tabernero aprovechaba la ebriedad de los clientes para aumentar la cantidad a pagar. Así cuando la "cuenta" realizada por el tabernero era sospechosa de haber sido aumentada, se comentaba; ¿No te habrás pasado de la cuenta (real)? (¿No te habrás equivocado al sumar?).

Igualmente existe otra expresión que viene a significar lo mismo y es "**No pasarse de la raya**", aunque existen muchas versiones, proviene igualmente de la "cuenta" o suma que se realizaba en las barras de las tabernas, pues a la hora de computar o sumar el total, se dibujaba una línea o raya, a partir de la cual se realiza la suma de los distintos sumandos y así se decía; "¿No te habrás pasado de la raya?", era la pregunta con la que se le espetaba al tabernero pensando el cliente que quizás se había excedido más allá de la línea de esa suma (raya), a partir de la cual había seguido añadiendo cosas figurativamente que no se habían consumido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda! No entiendo por qué me dieron un -1 si hasta un hispanohablante tampoco sabria explicar el significado de la palabra "cuenta" en este contexto y/o el origen de la expresión (con la excepción de Ustedes, que son expertos en el idioma español ‍♂️)

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti por darlas!